# Unable to add image field in drupal 7

Tags: php, image, drupal

Im new to drupal and right now I need to create node programmatically.

I'm able to create a simple node. But if I incorporate it with an  image field it always failed.

```
$file_path = drupal_realpath('tmp/test_image.jpg');
$file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $file_path,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($file_path),
    'status' => 1,
);
$copy = file_copy($file, 'public://sites/default/files/field/image/testing/', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $copy;
```

It always return me an error :(

```
The specified file could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
```

Comment: Check your image folder permission should have `644` & also check your system log as suggested in error..

Comment: Hello I already tried that before too. I even set the sites folder to 777. I checked the logs and here's what I got. "The image could not be copied, because the destination directory public:// is not configured correctly."

Comment: The default path to the `public` schema is `/sites/default/files` so if you want to save something in, for example, `/sites/default/files/my-images/image1.jpg` the URI would be `public://my-images/image1.jpg`. If you're saving this node as the result of a form submission I'd highly recommend looking at the [`managed file` type](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) which will handle all the file saving for you

Comment: Hello thank you for your input, I already got the public folder which is equivalent to the path you mentioned. The thing is it still returning that error. I already set the folder permission to 644. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
In my case the problem was that the media configuration "Public file system path" was setted as relative path sites/default/files. After that I setted the absolute path from root everything had worked

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you tell `file_copy()` to store in "public:", you shouldn't specify the full path name.  At least, in the examples I've seen, the target looks more like `'public:filename.ext'`.

As the comment above suggests, check your logs to be sure.  In addition to the web server's error log, see if Drupal has noted any further details in its Reports section.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this public directory works, because when I checked if its a directory, the result was false.

Answer (score 0):

`'public://'` = `'sites/default/files'` (or any other folder specified as default files folder) in Drupal way.

Your code:

```
$copy = file_copy($file, 'public://field/image/testing');
```

P.S. `FILE_EXISTS_RENAME` goes by default so it's not necessary to define it.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that still it doesnt work. This might be something to do with folder persmissions. But I already set the public folder as 644.

Comment: Public folder should be set to 777. Check your Drupal status if you have any errors there. If you would `print_r($copy)` after your `$copy = file_copy(...)`, what it will give you?

Comment: Ok, what `$file_path` return to you then?

Comment: I got the actual path where my file is located for ex. C:\xampp\htdocs\cybertron\hermes\images\test.jpg. The strange is the file_unmanaged_copy works though :( so I'm quite confused if its really the permission issue, Am I missing something here?

Comment: The problem is that your code works perfect. It's definitely folder permission. Seems like your site is on Windows system. Check out that your files folder and ALL folders inside has write  permission.

Comment: Yes I'm running windows system. When I set the file permissions I'm using a bash terminal.. So I could do like chmod etc.. Anyway, I just set it to other folder for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Public folder should never be 777. 755 for files, 644 for folders if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs. I tried setting the public path 'sites/default/files' to 'testing' or any other folder and set to 644.

It works. :(

Here's my updated code.

```
$file_path = drupal_realpath('test_image.jpg');
$file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $file_path,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($file_path),
    'status' => 1,
);
$copy = file_copy($file, 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

Im not sure what else permissions that i needed to set in sites and its sub folders.

Comment: Your files folder and all sub folders should be set to 777. Also, check if the owner of those folders is `www-data` and not any of your system users.